# To fix a bug in Less' command by noting no. of parameters

Tags: manpage, if-statement

This question is based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053707/unable-to-make-a-shell-function-in-bash-zsh).

**The code**

```
function man()
{       
    man "$1" > /tmp/manual; less /tmp/manual 
}
```

**Problem:** if I use even one option, the command does not know where is the wanted-manual

For instance,

```
man -k find
```

gives me an error, since the reference is wrong. The command reads `-k` as the manual.

**My attempt to solve the problem in pseudo-code**

```
if no parameters
    run the initial code
if one parameter
    run: man "$2"
...
```

In other words, we need to add an option-check to the beginning such that

**Pseudo-code**

```
    man $optional-option(s) "$n" > /tmp/manual; less /tmp/manual
```

where $n

- n=1 if zero options
- n=2 if 1 option
- n=3 if 2 options
- ....

**How can you make such an "option-check" that you can alter the value of $n?**

**Developed Problem:** to make two if loops for the situations from n=1 to n=2

Comment: @ Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about passing all the arguments

```
function man()
{       
    man $@ > /tmp/manual; less /tmp/manual 
}
```

What is the bug in less which you mention in the title?

Comment: $@ should probably be quoted. Otherwise `man "one two"` might be interpreted as `man one two`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can pass all of your function's arguments to `man` by using `$*` or `$@`. You can read `man sh` for the precise details on the difference between the two; short story is to almost always use `"$@"` with double quotes.

Second, the temporary file is unnecessary. You could make this a little cleaner by piping the output of `man` directly to `less`:

```
function man() {
    man "$@" | less
}
```

By the way, if you're just trying to use a different pager (`man` uses `more` and you want the fancier `less`) there's a commonly recognized `PAGER` environment variable that you can set to override the default pager. You could add this to your `~/.bashrc` for instance to tell all programs to use `less` when displaying multiple screens of output:

```
export PAGER=less
```

---

To answer your precise question, you can check the number of arguments with `$#`:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    : # No arguments
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    : # One argument
# etc.
```

You might also find the `shift` command helpful. It renames `$2` to `$1`, `$3` to `$2`, and so on. It is often used in a loop to process command-line arguments one by one:

```
while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
    echo "Next argument is: $1"
    shift
done

echo "Last argument is: $1"
```

Comment: I'm on a Mac and it works. You just need an sh-compatible shell.